# Update table in users_meta in MySQL(Not wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql

i want to perform update query a table where i am holding "User Meta Info".

I want to update the meta_value corresponds to "userid" = 9, in which multiple meta_key can be there to update. (This is not wordpress database)

My table looks like this:

```
umeta_id     userid      meta_key       meta_value
 1              9         mobile        123324
 2              9         address       some address
 3              9         city          some city
 4              9         country       some country
 5              9         occupation    some details
 6              9         website       someurl
 7              9         mobile        123324
 8              9         address       some address
 9              9         city          some city
 10             10        country       some country
 11             10        occupation    some details
 12             10        website       someurl
```

Please suggest some solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update 1***:

> If i want to update multiple values, which can be any meta_key which is not right now, but can be there. i am using PHP to update this my function looks like this
>
> ```
> public static function update
>   ( $fullname, $mobile, $interest, $occupation,
>     $address, $city, $country, $about, $‌​website ) {
>   $sql = "update user_meta SET ";
> };
> ```

You can use either a `CASE WHEN` or a `IF( ... )` condition to update multiple rows of a column.

Following example should help you.

**Using `IF(...)` function**:

```
update user_meta_info
  set
     meta_value = if( meta_key='mobile', '$mobile', meta_value ),
     meta_value = if( meta_key='address', '$address', meta_value ),
     meta_value = if( meta_key='city', '$city', meta_value ),
     meta_value = if( meta_key='country', '$country', meta_value ),
     meta_value = if( meta_key='occupation', '$occupation', meta_value ),
     meta_value = if( meta_key='website', '$website', meta_value )
where
  user_id = 9
```

**Using `CASE ... WHEN ...`**:

```
update user_meta_info
  set
     meta_value = case meta_key
                        when 'mobile' then '$mobile'
                        when 'address' then '$address'
                        when 'city' then '$city'
                        when 'country' then '$country'
                        when 'occupation' then '$occupation'
                        when 'website' then '$website'
                        else meta_value
                  end
where
  user_id = 9
```

---

You have to use `meta_key` in where clause to set a new value for `meta_value` column.

```
update user_meta_info
 set meta_value='new mobile number'
where
 user_id = 9 and
 meta_key = 'mobile'
```

And in case if each `meta_key` can have multiple meta values, then you must use `umeta_id` in where clause. And if `umeta_id` is a primary key, you can omit using other fields in where clause.

```
update user_meta_info
 set meta_value='new mobile number'
where
 umeta_id = 7 -- ( and user_id = 9 and meta_key = 'mobile' )
```

Comment: If i want to update multiple values, which can be any meta_key which is not right now, but can be there.

i am using PHP to update this my function looks like this 

public static function `update($fullname,$mobile,$interest,$occupation,$address,$city,$country,$about,$website){
  $sql = "update user_meta SET ";
 }`;

Comment: please check this link too, is possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157511/select-query-in-two-tables-in-mysql.

Someone already answered but looking for more dynamic way. in which i am not restrict with meta_key, means any number of meta key can be generated into coloum from row.

thank you! once again.

Comment: @user3201500: Yes. That solution is pivoting the data. Where as in this `update ...` it is done in a similar way.